# 301 редирект всего раздела (с вложенными подразделами и страницами)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, редирект

Здравствуйте
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать 301 редирект раздела и всех его подразделов и страниц на главную

пробовал так :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/.*$ / [L,R=301]
```

Не сработало

Comment: и как оно не сработало?

Comment: мне при переходе на sitename.ru/product или sitename.ru/product/page нужно чтоб переадресовывало на главную. То как я пример показал - не переадресовывает

Comment: я бы написал так `RewriteRule ^product(/.*)?$ / [L,R=301]` но, казалось бы, и ваш вариант должен работать

Comment: Благодарю!)
Такой вариант работает

Comment: Хотя теперь весь сайт редиректит на главную

Comment: очень странно. это весь htaccess ?

Comment: @splash58, пожалуйста, не используйте комментарии для ответов. Опубликуйте свое решение в качестве ответа

Comment: @VenZell так не работает же

Comment: @D.Nekrasov, проверьте, нет ли редиректов в коде (например, в php-файлах, если используется php). Покажите все содержимое `.htaccess`. Указанные правила не могут приводить к редиректу всех страниц на главную.